Can only pronouns be Anaphors or Cataphors?
I've had to change this example text to anonymize it, but I'm wondering whether "such" would correctly be labeled as an anaphor here:

Where a category A employee is absent and no replacement is available, management may ask category A employees to volunteer to cover the absent employee's duties during their scheduled break periods or ask category B employees to volunteer to cover the absent employee's duties, as needed. Any such loss in time will be recorded and may be taken by the employee as time off.

I'm trying to explain how the word "such" in this scenario refers back to the previous sentence, and implies that both of the scenarios contemplated in that sentence (category A employees covering during their break, category B employees covering) are "losses in time". Is it correct to explain this as follows?

"such" is an anaphor
the following clause is the corresponding cataphor: "management may ask category A employees to volunteer to cover the absent employee's duties during their scheduled break periods or ask category B employees to volunteer to cover the absent employee's duties"

Alternatively, am I completely misunderstanding anaphora, and only pronouns can be anaphors? Thanks in advance for your feedback!

I'd have thought the anaphor was Any such loss in time, but this terminology (my example anaphor) isn't my strong suit.

It's anaphora and cataphora. The first goes back to something; the second goes forward. No, not just pronouns.

I don’t think “such” is used correctly here, as it doesn’t really refer to anything. It’s actually unnecessary. Alternatively one could say “Any resulting loss in time” . . .

It's not terribly clear - presumably the employee skipping breaks isn't causing a loss of time (?), so it relates to implication that an employee covering for someone else in their work hours will result in a loss of time spent on something else, but even that will depend on how time is accounted - the entire time spent covering may or may not be lost time depending on what the employee would be doing otherwise. I think you need something more specific to explain exactly what time you're talking about and what qualifies as a loss of time.

@StuartF Agreed, it is unclear. Unfortunately this is the structure I'm stuck with, and my job is to interpret it. My understanding (admittedly instinctual, as English is my first language) is that if it read "Any loss in time", that means that we need to look elsewhere to determine what it means for time to be lost. However, because the word "such" is there, it would suggest that the previous sentenced contains the answer to the question of what a loss in time is. I'm just struggling to explain why I think this.

Some dictionaries consider that "such" may also work as pronoun (see here).
The anaphoric usage of "such" is supported according to what is also stated in the aforementioned link.
such

Referring back.

Such a thing or person means a thing or person like the one that has just  been described, mentioned, or experienced.
We could not believe such a thing.
Collins COBUILD English Usage ©

What if instead of this:

Any such loss in time will be recorded and may be taken by the employee as time off.

you said:

Any loss in time under those circumstances will be recorded and may be taken by the employee as time off.

The point of the question being, do you consider "demonstratives" anaphors, and that leads to the question what, exactly, is an anaphor?
Is a verbal "nod", as it were, in the direction of the aforementioned circumstances truly anaphoric?  Or must an anaphor be syntactically co-referential, not merely linked  or anchored on a semantic level?
I take such as a semantic allusion in the sentence above, not as a co-referential syntactic stand-in.

Nordquist allows for other words / strings than pronouns to be considered anaphors* [bolding mine]:

In English grammar, "anaphora" is the use of a pronoun or other
linguistic unit to refer back to another word or phrase. The
adjective is anaphoric, and the term is also known by the phrases
anaphoric reference or backward anaphora. A word that gets its meaning
from a preceding word or phrase is called an anaphor. The preceding
word or phrase is called the antecedent, referent, or head.
Some linguists use anaphora as a generic term for both forward and
backward reference. The phrase forward(s) anaphora is equivalent to
cataphora.

For completeness:

Anaphora and cataphora are the two main types of endophora — that is,
reference to an item within the text itself.

Later in the article:

"The most widespread type of anaphora is that of pronominal anaphora.
. . ."
– Ruslan Mitkov, Anaphora Resolution. Routledge, 2013

                                                                                                      

Note that 'anaphora' is also used in count form as an alternative plural of 'anaphor'.

